# How to pass an object's method to an external function

Tags: c++, object

Given an object named `myObj` with functions `doThis` and `doThat`, what is the best way to pass the object (and the directive to a function) to an external function?

As an example of how I am currently doing this, I an external function `void whatToDo( myClass myObj, string myFunction)` where I simply pass in either `doThis` or `doThat` as `myFunction` and check it:

```
void whatToDo( myClass myObj, string myFunction) {
    if( myFunction == "doThis") myObj.doThis();
    if( myFunction == "doThat") myObj.doThat();
}
```

However, as the class grows, this becomes a worse and worse option. Is there a way to pass the actual function to `whatToDo` so that I can just call it directly?

Comment: Use Pointer-To-Member (function).

Comment: Are you going to do anything else with the object besides call this method on it? Are you going to use this same member function on other objects? If no to both, you could just take one argument (a template parameter), and pass a function object (either using a lambda, or `std::bind`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what pointers to member functions are for:

```
void whatToDo(myClass& myObj, void (myClass::*p)())
{
    // p is a pointer to a member function class myClass that
    // takes no arguments and returns void

    // you can invoke it thusly
    (myObj.*p)();
}
```

You could provide such pointers as:

```
struct myClass {
    void doThis();
    void doThat();
};

myClass c;
whatToDo(c, &myClass::doThis); // will invoke c.doThis();
whatToDo(c, &myClass::doThat); // will invoke c.doThat();
```