# Using OpenMP while calling using a pointer to a method

Tags: c++, thread-safety, openmp

I [recently learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960106/how-to-pass-an-objects-method-to-an-external-function/36960172#36960172) how to pass an object's method to a function for evaluation and now I would like to use `OpenMP` on a loop while calling this method. The actual code is:

```
std::vector< std::vector< double > > grid2D( wfn& W, double (wfn::*p)(double, double, double), std::vector< double > xs, std::vector< double > ys, double z ) { 
    std::vector< std::vector< double > > fs; 
    int nx = (int)xs.size();
    int ny = (int)ys.size();

    fs.resize(nx);
    for(int ix = 0; ix < nx; ix++) {
        fs[ix].resize(ny);
        for(int iy = 0; iy < ny; iy++) {
            fs[ix][iy] = (W.*p)( xs[ix], ys[iy], z); 
        }   
    }   

    return fs; 
}
```

where `wfn` represents the "wavefunction" of a molecule and has many, many private variables stored to represent the physics.

If I insert `#pragma omp parallel for` above the loop over `iy`, the grid generation of `fs[ix][iy]` is incorrect. Is there a way to pass `W.*p` as private to this `#pragma` so that the evaluation of `p` is threadsafe?

Comment: Is p a `const` method? Can you pass `W` as `const`? If not, what happens with the state of `W` inside `p`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide much detail about the exact #pragma omp statement you insert before the second for loop. I assume you don't declare any variable private, therefore all variables inside to loop are assumed shared. This leads to threads modifying data in an unpredictable way. You can declare variables private by adding private(list_of_variables) to the statement. You might want to start with adding "default(none)" (without the quotation marks) to the #pragma omp statement and declare all variables as private. Then you can start removing one by one variables from the list and declaring them shared. Of course after each modification you need to recompile and run your code again. Sometimes this process takes a while to get it right. So you can start with

#pragma omp parallel for default(none) private(W,xs,ys,iy,fs,z) firstprivate(ix)

Depending on the version of OMP you are using, the loop variable iy might be private by default.